# Spell Checker doesn't work on CKEditor 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor, javascript

I'm using CKEditor v4.0 and ckeditor gem https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails

Gemfile

```
gem 'ckeditor', '>= 4.0.0.rc1'
```

config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ){
   config.skin = 'moono',
   config.disableNativeSpellChecker = true,
   config.scayt_autoStartup = true,
   config.toolbar = [ 
      [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Blockquote', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink', '-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt' ]
   ]
};
```

I've been testing many possible solutions, I think that it is a problem with v4.0

https://www.outsystems.com/NetworkForums/ViewTopic.aspx?TopicId=7033&Topic=CKEditor---Spell-Check-As-You-Type-(-SCAYT-)

http://devnet.kentico.com/FAQs/Content-Management/Enable-the-Spell-Check-As-You-Type-feature-by-defa.aspx

In here http://drupal.org/node/1870398 user called "vinmassaro " posted that if you set "Spell Check as You Type" on toolbar it work because the two type of spellcheck was compress in one button, but dosent work, not even the toolbar button it is shown :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how fix this but I found another gem that can do what I want, and if you want to use this feature you can use it with out any extra configuration.

```
gem 'ckeditor_rails', '~> 4.0.1.1'
```

https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails